# Why is the data still in one shard after hashed sharding an existing collection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

This is the state before I turn on the sharding:

[image]

This is after I turned on sharding  status:

[image]

The data still in one shard after hashed sharding an existing collection in mongodb.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: What do you get from `db.collection.getShardDistribution()`? Most likely you simply have still too few documents for sharding. Did you enable sharding on database level?